# What is assembly in C# in the context of internal access modifier?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, protected, access-modifiers, .net-internals

I thought that assembly is a project in a solution in Visual Studio, but then I was trying to understand inheritance and internal/protected access modifiers and I got lost.
*`Project1` and `Project2` are separate VS projects in one solution:

```
namespace Project1
{
    public class C1
    {
        internal int field1;
        internal protected int field2;
    }
}
```

```
namespace Project2
{
    public class C2
    {
        public static void f(C1 c1)
        {
            c1.field1 = 1;  //no problems here
            c1.field2 = 2;  //neither here
        }
    }
}
```

In `Project2` I have no inheritance so both fields `field1` and `field2` should be inaccessible but there's no errors at all. (I added Project1 into Project2 References and add `using Project1` in `Project2`)

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about this? I get the expected behaviour.

Comment: I guess you're still in same project despite of the different namespace. Can you confirm this? May be `C1` class exist in both projects by mistake? If not, can you share some screenshot or a sample project? Also make sure you're not using `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`

Comment: @Rotem I'm afraid yes https://i.imgur.com/P45J6Sc.png https://i.imgur.com/n43A3EP.png

Comment: Here's a dumb question. Could you try running the code? Does it just let you compile, or does it let you run?

Comment: @Shriike I tried to run it and I didn't get any compilation or run errors

Comment: Did you first create `C1` and `C2` in the same project? Try cleaning the solution, removing all assemblies from the bin folders and compile again.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I don't even know what InternalsVisibleToAttribute is, so I did not use it intentionally :)

Comment: @CodeCaster No, all classes was created as you can see on screenshots (separately)

Comment: Delete all the files in Bin, then try to recompile and see if that compiles fine(Go and check binaries are created in bin). If it does, can you share the project with us(through some file sharing website)? so that we can also see the problem?

Comment: seems that cleaning filed in Bins doesn't help. I tried to make a new solutions with this projects and share it with you. Just wait a sec :)

Comment: Open Configuration Manager and check Build for both libraries. I guess your first try was without internal modifier, then you added it and works in unexpected way. That's because your libraries are not rebuilded.

Comment: http://www.speedyshare.com/FnkM2/Solution1.zip All I did is copy paste the code you can see above, add Project1 to Project2 references and add `using Project1` co Project2 code

Comment: Your project is broken, I managed to add the files in place and tried to compile. Compiler error occurs without any surprise. I'm voting to close as *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior* If you can share a code which can reproduce the problem. I'll retract my vote. http://imgur.com/aWkpu2B

Comment: Eemm... you hava all code above, in question. I didn't make anything more than I wrote in comment before :/ It is new Solution with new Projects. Just copy paste the code. I don't know what could get wrong.

Comment: That's weird. Seems the project is really broken...

Comment: As you can see the image I linked in above comment, I can't reproduce the problem. Also your project is broken. I mean two program files are missing, C1 and C2 classes was not added in project. Try to open the solution which you shared us in Visual studio and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Yes I noticed that. Now I'm trying to share correct solution

Comment: OK I tried open this and it worked (except no expected errors) http://www.speedyshare.com/Qfhep/Solution2.zip

Comment: "Your field1 and field2 are public..." Eh, some error in copying

Comment: http://www.speedyshare.com/WbSPP/Solution2.zip access modifiers are improved, main added, bin folders deleted befor building. Still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution works, because it contains errors that Visual Studio can ignore.

You have a fully functional project Project1, containing a `Main()`. This is the project that is set as startup project, which can run because it contains no errors.

Not all project in your solution have to successfully build in order for one project to run; just the projects that the project you want to run depends on. In this case none.

Right-click Project2, click "Set as StartUp Project" and try to build or run it: you'll see the compiler errors you're expecting.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/XhKfGPE.png field1 error is a bit strange. And I'm still don't know why VS doesn't highlight this lines as errors (as it does at others screenshots)

Comment: Because `field1` is marked `assembly` and `field2` is marked `famorassem` in IL. The compiler simply cannot see `field1`, while `field2` _can_ be seen, as it is `protected`, and thus can be used by classes inheriting from `C1` (even from different assemblies despite it being `protected internal`, see [Access Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx): _"The type or member can be accessed by any code in the assembly in which it is declared, or from within a derived class in another assembly."_).

Comment: OK, I get it, but why all you guys get nice warnings during coding and I have so much problems just to see the problem really exists?

Comment: Because there were multiple errors with the different projects. Errors are cascading, if at the beginning something goes wrong, you won't see errors generated further on. For example when in your bin folder there was an assembly containing `C1` with public fields.

Comment: OK then, lets assume that I understand what's go wrong and I hope I'll never get something similar in the future. Thanks for all your help guys

Answer (score 0):

[Internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) is an access modifier in which the class, method, or property is exposed to any class that is also embedded within the same assembly.

However classes, methods, or properties that are declared internal are NOT exposed to classes belonging to other assemblies.

Comment: I know that but if VS Project == assembly then something weird is happening in my code right now...

Comment: What are the assemblies?